# RewriteRule only when action=logout query string is NOT present

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm customizing my WordPress login page. Here's what I want to achieve:

```
/wp-login.php → /login  
/wp-login.php?action=register → /login?action=register  
/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=eaea03899c → NOT redirected
```

I can't redirect the logout link because /login will not log the user out, only wp-login.php is able to do that.

How can I achieve the above? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want `/wp-login.php?action=register → /login?action=logout` redirected to action=logout?

Comment: @Virendra whoops you're right, thanks for catching that. I've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you need. It would redirect all `wp-login.php?query=string` to `/login?query=string`, except when `action=logout` is present in the querystring. (Also, assuming you want to keep the query string as it is and not change it.)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !action=logout [NC]
RewriteRule wp-login.php /login [L,R=301]
```

**Update**: Here are the rules to just redirect `wp-login.php` and `wp-login.php?action=register`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^action=register$ [NC]
RewriteRule wp-login.php /login [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^wp-login.php /login [R=301,L]
```

Note the rule to forward `wp-login.php?action=register` will work only when the URL is `wp-login.php?action=register`. It will not work if there are any other query parameters. If you want it to work if `action=register` is present in the URL irrespective of any other parameters or its location then use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=register [NC]
RewriteRule wp-login.php /login [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I tried your code and it worked.. but now I cannot login. I think it's because the POST action is also being sent to wp-login.php. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure how we can forward the POST request (if we can).

Comment: No.. not really. Do you know how I can redirect *only* `wp-login.php` and `wp-login.php?action=register`. Those are the only 2 I need to redirect, and shouldn't interfere with WordPress' lostpassword, logout, etc actions.